# Cannot add lifecycle rules for bucket in Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Trying to create a bucket and add lifecycle rule for it via python but get an error.

Code:

```
def bucketscreate(bucket_name):
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage.Bucket(client, name='gc_' + bucket_name + '_consul_storage')
    bucket.location = "us-east1"
    bucket.storage_class = "NEARLINE"
    try:
        bucket = client.create_bucket(bucket)
    except Conflict:
        print("Bucket gc_" + bucket_name + "_consul_storage exists.")
    bucket = client.get_bucket('gc_' + bucket_name + '_consul_storage')
    rules = {
            "action": {"type": "Delete"},
            "condition": {
                "age": 3
            }
        }
    bucket.lifecycle_rules = rules
    bucket.retention_period = 10
    bucket.patch()
    return bucket.name
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./consul_dump.py", line 103, in <module>
    bucketscreate(argv)
  File "./consul_dump.py", line 37, in bucketscreate
    bucket.lifecycle_rules = rules
  File "/home/sahaquiel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py", line 2019, in lifecycle_rules
    rules = [dict(rule) for rule in rules]  # Convert helpers if needed
  File "/home/sahaquiel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py", line 2019, in <listcomp>
    rules = [dict(rule) for rule in rules]  # Convert helpers if needed
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Help me pls to understand what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rules should be a list. Try this:

```
 rules = [{
        "action": {"type": "Delete"},
        "condition": {
            "age": 3
        }
 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set lifecycle rules on your bucket using python without needing a dict or list:

```py
# age is in days
bucket.add_lifecycle_delete_rule(age=175)

# .patch() is needed to push changes to gcp
bucket.patch()
```

Or if you want to change the storage class:

```
# set storage to nearline after 5 days
bucket.add_lifecycle_set_storage_class_rule(age=5, storage_class='NEARLINE')
bucket.patch()
```

The following storage classes are available:
`'STANDARD', 'NEARLINE', 'COLDLINE', 'ARCHIVE'`

See also:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-enable-bucket-lifecycle-management